# How do I start a DevTools user flow recording from a dynamic URL?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Google recently released their [DevTools user flow recorder](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/recorder/) and it seems like an interesting and easy-to-use tool. One limitation I'm running into is that replaying a recording will always bring you to the page you initiated the recording on. For example, if I create and save a recording on [this array processing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array) then navigate to [this git question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git), running the recording on the latter will redirect me back to the former. I would like to be able to make a recording, then kick it off from whatever page I'm currently viewing. So far, I've tried both removing the URL from the initial step and replacing the initial URL with a JS IIFE that gets the current URL; neither of these have worked.